# If I force ifort to inline a function, should I expect to still see it in an obj dump?

Tags: fortran, inline, symbols, intel-fortran

If I add this above the definition of a module procedure

```
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES FORCEINLINE :: procedure
```

can I confirm that inline was done by checking if the procedure is present in the symbol table, i.e.

```
objdump -t my_program | grep procedure
```

I am expecting for an inlined function, the symbol to not be present.

Comment: What do you observe?  In general I think the answer is no - as there would be cases where the symbol would still need to be in object code, even though all invocations of the procedure in that object code were inlined.

Comment: I observe that the symbol is still present. I was questioning if I was doing things right, however. I was hoping I'd see some sort of compiler output, particularly using the FORCEINLINE feature, indicating if inlining could or could not be accomplished. Unfortunately, no such output, hence I was turning to objdump for backup.

Comment: You could always inspect the assembly, if you wanted to confirm inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect that, unless you used -ipo. Otherwise, the compiler has to assume that you might pass the procedure as an actual argument.

Comment: By the way, Steve Lionel, real quick, big fan of iFort. Thanks for help keeping Fortran compilers modern.